# How do I log events in Windows IoT?

Tags: c#, powershell, win-universal-app, etw, windowsiot

WebUI for Windows IoT (as seen on Raspberry PI) features the following Event Tracing screen:

[image]

How do I write into an event log from a uwp program and then later examine what's written there?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32196161/284111) (which is not about Windows IoT) suggests that you need to use standard System.Diagnostics.Tracing classes for it. The sample that this answer is referring to is to demonstrate logging to *a file*. I'm more after logging to a built-in facility, such as ETW.

Following similar logic as in the sample I'm executing [EventSource.Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393391(v=vs.110).aspx) and it does not throw a error, but written message is nowhere to be seen.

Windows Powershell for Window IoT does not support Get-EventLog command either.

Windows IoT development is relatively new, so there is not much information in the internet. The best source currently is [Ms Iot Samples](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples) but despite huge number of samples none of them seem to be doing any event logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Read and understand [EventSource User’s Guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing/EventSource/docs/EventSource.md)
2. Add a class to your project that derives from [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) and implement your methods as described in the linked guide. A sample implementation is available [here](https://gist.github.com/AndrewSav/70c0c46ba180a0770c3d7510ff392fb4).
3. Build your project, locate project output (yourProject.winmd)
4. Get EventRegister.exe utility from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister/)
5. Run `EventRegister.exe -UsersGuide`. Read and understand usage.
6. Run `eventRegister.exe -DumpRegDlls yourProject.winmd`. This will generate `yourProject.MyEwtProvider.etwManifest.dll` and `yourProject.MyEwtProvider.etwManifest.man` files.
7. Create a new folder on your Windows IoT device, for example, `C:\Events` or use an existing one.
8. Open `yourProject.MyEwtProvider.etwManifest.man` in an editor and edit `resourceFileName` and `messageFileName` paths so that the parent folder is `C:\Events`
9. Copy `yourProject.MyEwtProvider.etwManifest.dll` and `yourProject.MyEwtProvider.etwManifest.man` over to your Windows IoT to the `C:\Events` folder. *Note: the simplest way to do this is to open windows share as `\\yourdevice\c$` in Windows Explorer*
10. Connect to your Windows IoT with Powershell. Run `cd C:\Events`
11. Run `wevtutil.exe im .\yourProject.MyEwtProvider.etwManifest.man`. This should not produce any warnings or errors. Please refer to [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx) for the details on `wevtutil.exe` syntax.

Now if you navigate to your ETW WebUI page as in your question "MyEwtProvider" will appear in the drop down. You log events in your program by calling one of the `UwpEventSource.Log.Info/Warn/Debug/Critical/Error("Hello from my porgram");`

If you do not want to collect the events when you are not working with the WebUI you are done. If you want to be able to persist these and analyse them later, run the following command in your powershell session:

```
echo y | wevtutil.exe sl MyEwtProvider/Debug /e:true
```

See what it does [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/14/automatically-enable-and-disable-trace-logs-using-powershell/). Now you will be able to retrieve historical data (once you've accumulated them) by running:

```
wevtutil.exe qe MyEwtProvider/Debug
```

Comment: Can I ask what project types you are using? I'm compiling for Raspberry Pi and my project is not generating a winmd file. I tried moving the event source class to a "Windows Runtime Component" project, but that won't accept the inheritance from EventSource.

Comment: @Jasper, the project type is "Class Library (Universal Widnows)" and then in project property the output type is selected to be "Windows Runtime Component"

Comment: As soon as I switch output to Windows Runtime Component, I'm getting these build errors: "Windows Runtime class 'MyApp.Universal.Log.MinimalEventSource' has an invalid base type, 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource'.  Classes must derive either from System.Object or from a composable Windows Runtime class.  Implementation inheritance is not allowed."

Comment: @Jasper What does your `project.json` look like?

Comment: {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}

Comment: @Jasper, I'll try and publish the project for you, the problem is that I need to remove all irrelevant stuff from it and it will take some time, which currently I do not have. So no promises, but I'll do my best.

Comment: Would be awesome @zespri, I'm still struggling with this one