# speech recognition not working in raspberry pi 3(windows iot core) using UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

```
 var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
            await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
            var webSearchGrammar = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint
                (Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionScenario.WebSearch, "webSearch");
            speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(webSearchGrammar);
            await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
            SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
            var question = speechRecognitionResult;
```

This is the code i am using to recognize speech in uwp, the solution is working in local but when deployed in raspberry pi, it's not able to recognize the speech. I also updated the latest version of windows10 iot core. Before updating windows 10 iot core it worked in raspberry pi but after updation it's not able to recognize(it's an observation)

Comment: Which build windows iot core did you use that the app worked on?

Comment: In visual studio 2015 Build 10586. In visual studio 2017 Build 17134

Comment: @Raviteja I think Michael means what version of windows IOT are you using, not the visual studio build version

Comment: I am not shure about it, but i found this under OS (10.0.17134.48) in my device list

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the upgraded device has provided Voice Permission from Cortana. If not, you need to launch cortana on your device, please refer to this document about [Cortana On IoT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/extend-your-app/cortanaoniotcore). When using [Speech recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/speech-recognition), we should ensure that device has a microphone or the equivalent, and provides the Privacy for Speech, inking, and typing.

Comment: Thank you @Michael, we have tried it in a different way by formatting the SD card and re-installing windows iot core again in it, it worked. I just want know whether there will be any improvement in recognition of speech if we launch cortana on our device

Comment: @Raviteja, Windows IoT Core 17134 has new language APIs for setting the preferred user language, region, default speech language, and default voice. You can get the release note  from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/currentcommercial).

Comment: after re-installation speech recognization is working fine yesterday, but today we came across with same speech recognition issue in raspberry. An observation is that we did not found cortana in our app manager yesterday but today i see cortana running in app manager. How to resolve this speech recognizer issue, there is no difference in code from yesterday to today

Comment: Have you traced the event log for monitoring the Cortana process dump?You can try to trace the event log via this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673208/how-do-i-log-events-in-windows-iot)?